# Apply numpy functions to pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a DataFrame where each element is a numpy array and I would like to apply to them numpy functions.

here is an example:

```
a=pd.DataFrame({'x':[np.array([1,2]),np.array([10,20])],'y':[np.array([3,4]),np.array([30,40])]})
```

now let's try to apply `np.dot` along `axis=1`

if I try

```
a.apply(lambda row: np.dot(row[0],row[1]), axis=1)
```

I get the correct result result. By the way I do not get why this simpler line:

```
a.apply(np.dot, axis=1)
```

exits with a TypeError:

> TypeError: ("Required argument 'b' (pos 2) not found", u'occurred at
>   index 0')

I'm guessing it is because all the vector are passed as the first argument of dot; isn't it? If so there is a better way to work around than my previous solution?

Comment: You're right about the `dot` only getting the first argument in the second example. Typically you'll want to avoid having arrays or lists as elements of `DataFrames`, if possible. So your best solution might be to restructure your data, perhaps a list of `DataFrames` or a `Panel` would be better.

Comment: I see... well I can break down the arrays in different series and then operating on them as vectors using values. Is it a time-wasting idea?

Comment: That would fit better with the way pandas is structured. There are a lot of operations and efficiencies lost when the elements of a dataframe are lists or arrays, so it may be time-saving.